# Is it possible to hide files from Terminal's ls?

Tags: terminal, macos, malware

I am saving some files because I need to reinstall OS X, and noticed oddly high numbers of files in some folders. Is it possible for malware to hide files from `ls`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hidden files are hidden from ls unless you use the `-a` or `-A` flag:

```
-A   List all entries except for . and ...  Always set for the super-user.
-a   Include directory entries whose names begin with a dot (.).
```

<sup>Source: [ls man page](http://cl.ly/UwEB)</sup>

**Therefore, files can be hidden by starting the filename with a `.`** but ls will still show the file if it is run with `-a` or `-A`.

Note that not all files that are hidden with a . are malware-related. The system creates many files like this for a variety of reasons in various places on the disk that can cause problems if removed or modified.

Comment: one additional note: there are many legitimate files the OS hides in this manner. Finding files using `ls -a` does not indicate the presence of malware.

Comment: @dwightk I know, but maybe other people reading this don't. (grgarside: maybe include it in the answer, as some people - including me - do not always read all the comments.)

Answer (score 2):

ls is not a command that opens the directory file itself and show it's contents. It uses dirent (Directory Entries) from the C library which is used by a lot of software like stat but also bash's parameter expansion.

So the real question is then: Is it possible for malware to hide files from BSD/Darwin? **No, you can't hide files from it's own system** because it will turn into waste (read:free to overwrite) very soon.

Comment: What is this command "Ls"? :)